# PHP define() unsafe to use for mysql database variables?

Tags: php

As the question states, is it unsafe to use define() for password/login/table names etc.

Example:

```
//database server
define('DB_SERVER', "localhost");

//database login name
define('DB_USER', "root");
//database login password
define('DB_PASS', "");
```

Comment: Unsafe in which way? This is fairly common practice.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone `get_defined_constants()`

Answer (score 2):

It isn't really unsafe. But to bse sure you have to make sure the files where you add this is outside of your DocumentRoot. But you only have your bootstrap file inside the DocumentRoot right? :-)

Answer (score 1):

No it's not unsafe, it's just storing the values in constants. Those constants will only be visible to your script.

Comment: But I read that these constants are available across the scope, meaning that if somehow injected code was put into my code (lets just say god did this or so). then they would be able to access the varibles anywhere?

Comment: Question: Can I force these constants to only work within certain files/directories?

Comment: @KarlMorrison Well, they do have global scope, so they will be visible from anywhere in your script, or included files. You cannot restrict it to certain files/dirs, but you can just not include the file where those constants are defined.